# Make randoms be different

Tags: android, random

I have this randoms:

```
    final Random rand2 = new Random();
    int number1 = rand2.nextInt(10) + 1;
    final Random rand3 = new Random();
    int number2 = rand3.nextInt(10) + 1;
    final Random rand4 = new Random();
    int number3 = rand4.nextInt(10) + 1;
    final Random rand5 = new Random();
    int number4 = rand5.nextInt(10) + 1;
    final Random rand6 = new Random();
    int number5 = rand6.nextInt(10) + 1;
    final Random rand7 = new Random();
    int number6 = rand7.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

My problem is, im setting text's to:

1.number1+number2

2.number3+number4

3.number5+number6.

What I need is to make sure text1 will be different from text2, and text3 will be different from text1, and text2 will be different from text3, it means:

```
(number1 + number2) != (number3 + number4)
&& (number3 + number4) != (number5 + number6)
&& (number5 + number6) != (number1 + number2)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new `Random` object for each new number.  Call `rand.nextInt()` on the first Random object repeatedly instead.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int number1 = rand.nextInt();
int number2 = rand.nextInt();
...etc
```

To verify uniqueness, put each generated number in a [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), and use the `contains()` method to see if it's already been used.

Comment: How can I do it? Can you give me an example? what the rand.Next() doing?

Comment: It's giving you the next `Int` number in the random sequence.  Creating a new Random generator for each new number will almost certainly give you an incorrect result.  See my example.

Comment: Ty, but the texts may be still the same, for example, number1 = 3, number2=4(together 7), number 3=5, number4=2(together 7)...

Comment: You'll have to check each next number against the previous ones.